# Expectation of a scaled random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value

Suppose we have 2 continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $Y = cX$ for a $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The probability density of $X$ range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I know that the expectation values of $X$ and $Y$ are also related by the same constant $c$:
$$E[Y] = cE[X]$$

However, I am having trouble showing this mathematically.

For $X$, where $\rho_x(x)$ is its probability density:
$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \rho_x(x) \,dx$$

For $Y$ (using $y=cx$):
$$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \rho_y(y) \,dy$$
$$= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (cx) \rho_x(cx) c\,dx$$
$$= c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x (c\rho_x(cx)) \,dx$$

Comparing this with $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \rho_x(x) \,dx$, I just need to show that $c\rho_x(cx)=\rho_x(x)$, but I am not sure this would always hold for an arbitrary $\rho_x(x)$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It woldn't be $\mathbb{E}[cX]=\int cxf_{X}(x)dx = c\int xf_{X}(x)dx$?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the analysis, apart from the implicit assumption $c\gt 0.$ (When $c\le 0$ your result is incorrect.)

Comment: Agree with Fiodor, you don't put the C inside f(x). Then everything works out.

Comment: Ah, I had assumed in my problem statement that $E[y]$ is the expectation of $y$ on the same probability density $\rho_x$ with respect to $x$.